# Switch XAML resources at runtime based on light/dark theme?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, theming

I have a WPF application that uses MahApps ("light" mode) and I've now provided a way for the user to switch modes (light/dark). A lot of the app's colours obviously change depending on the mode, as can be seen by comparing the \Styles\Themes\Light.*colour_name*.xaml & Dark.*colour_name*.xaml files, but I would like to "extend" these in some way by implementing my own xaml `<Color>` resources that also change depending on the selected mode. Can this be done?

One example is charts that currently use blue to plot the points - these look fine in "light" mode but are a bit dark in "dark" mode. I realise I could just use a more suitable shade of blue that looks okay in both modes, but it would be more flexible if I could define a Color resource that is (say) 'Blue' in light mode but 'Lime' in dark mode. There are likely to be other uses for such a feature too, e.g. coloured notification messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create custom themes based on the built-in themes. Create a resource dictionary that merges the resource dictionary of the base theme and override existing brushes and add new ones.

Light theme dictionary (`Light.Blue.Custom.xaml`):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" >
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

   <!-- Overriding default brushes -->
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Button.Border.MouseOver" Color="Blue" options:Freeze="True" />

   <!-- Adding your own brushes -->
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="My.Brushes.Notification.Alert" Color="Red" options:Freeze="True" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Dark theme dictionary (`Dark.Blue.Custom.xaml`):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:options="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" >
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Dark.Blue.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

   <!-- Overriding default brushes -->
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.Button.Border.MouseOver" Color="DarkBlue" options:Freeze="True" />

   <!-- Adding your own brushes -->
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="My.Brushes.Notification.Alert" Color="DarkRed" options:Freeze="True" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Register the theme dictionary in your application. You **must replace** the dummy name `YourApp` with the real name of your application in both the class and the resource dictionary URI.

```
public partial class YourApp : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var lightBlueCustomTheme = ThemeManager.Current.AddLibraryTheme(new LibraryTheme(
            new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourApp;component/Light.Blue.Custom.xaml"),
            MahAppsLibraryThemeProvider.DefaultInstance));

        var darkBlueCustomTheme = ThemeManager.Current.AddLibraryTheme(new LibraryTheme(
            new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourApp;component/Dark.Blue.Custom.xaml"),
            MahAppsLibraryThemeProvider.DefaultInstance));

        ThemeManager.Current.ChangeTheme(this, lightBlueCustomTheme);
        
        // Optionally enable App Mode theme switching
        // ThemeManager.Current.ThemeSyncMode = ThemeSyncMode.SyncWithAppMode;
        // ThemeManager.Current.SyncTheme();
    }
}
```

Note that you need to provide themes for **both** *Light* and *Dark*, if you want to switch modes. For more information about themes and customization, you can refer to the [documentation](https://mahapps.com/docs/themes/thememanager).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid going down the route of overriding every MahApps theme resource file, but I guess it's a necessary evil!